# how to fix error: input item in dynamodb with lambda python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I have some problem with using lambda and dynamodb.

this is my python code:

```
import json
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    client = boto3.client('dynamodb', region_name='ap-northeast-2')
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-northeast-2')

    response = client.put_item(
        TableName='tablename',
        Item = {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': 'value2',
            'key3': 'value3',
            'key4': 'value4'
                }
        )
```

and this is the error log:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Parameter validation failed:\nInvalid type for parameter Item.key1, value: value1, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>\nInvalid type for parameter Item.key2, value: value2, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>\nInvalid type for parameter Item.key3, value: value3, type: <class 'str'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>\nInvalid type for parameter Item.key4, value: value4, type: <class 'int'>, valid types: <class 'dict'>",
  "errorType": "ParamValidationError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 8, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.put_item(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 316, in _api_call\n    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 598, in _make_api_call\n    request_dict = self._convert_to_request_dict(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/client.py\", line 646, in _convert_to_request_dict\n    request_dict = self._serializer.serialize_to_request(\n",
    "  File \"/var/runtime/botocore/validate.py\", line 297, in serialize_to_request\n    raise ParamValidationError(report=report.generate_report())\n"
  ]
}
```

I had searched about parameter validation failed error, and aws said i have to download or upgrade pip3 and AWS CLI so i did. but it still makes error.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was busy doing sth else, Sorry for late check

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The boto3 SDK offers two `put_item()` methods, one is [client-level](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item) and one is [resource-level](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Table.put_item). They are different, in particular the way that you provide the item attributes is different. You are using the client-level API but passing attributes as if you were using the resource-level API.

Here is how you use the resource level API:

```
import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-northeast-2')
    table = dynamodb.table('tablename')

    response = table.put_item(
        Item = {
            'key1': 'value1',
            'key2': 'value2',
            'key3': 'value3',
            'key4': 'value4'
        }
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax doesn't seem to be correct. See example from https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.put_item

```py
response = client.put_item(
    Item={
        'AlbumTitle': {
            'S': 'Somewhat Famous',
        },
        'Artist': {
            'S': 'No One You Know',
        },
        'SongTitle': {
            'S': 'Call Me Today',
        },
    },
    ReturnConsumedCapacity='TOTAL',
    TableName='Music',
)
```

Values are not strings, but rather instances of `AttributeValue` type